# Pop to root view controller after sharing from sharekit

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I am using sharekit in my app for posting text to twitter. The thing is i need to pop to the root view controller (main controller) when the user clicks the send to twitter button in modal view.how to do this?

Comment: Is the modal displayed over the Main View controller?

Comment: no its in another view controller

Answer (score 0):

If you're running iOS 5 or above you can use TWTweetComposer to send tweets rather than ShareKit or the Social framework in iOS 6.

But if you want to use sharekit you'll need a delegate for your modalView.

You need to create a protocol. In the modal view header use something like

```
@protocol TwitterModalDelegate
-(void)closeModal;
@end
```

Then implement an id that conforms to that protocol as a property or ivar (usually called delegate)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TwitterModalDelegate> delegate
```

Now in your view controller presenting the modal tell it that it uses the protocol.

```
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController <TwitterModalDelegate>
```

You will need to import the modal view header into your ViewController header.

You now control what happens when the modal view closes.

```
-(void)closeModal
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
   {  
      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
   }];

}
```

So in your modal view when you confirm that the tweet has been sent you can simply call

```
[self.delegate closeModal];
```

Remember when creating an instance of the modal view to:

```
YourModalView* modalView = [YourModalView alloc]init];
modalView.delegate = self
[self presentViewController:modalView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: can u suggest me how to do it in share kit..because i tried but its not working. i may have done mistakes.. help me

Answer (score 0):

set your sharekit instance delegate to your current controller and implement (void)sharerFinishedSending:(SHKSharer *)sharer; this is sharekit delegate method to handle finished request